# Create raport with totals

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, pivot

I need to create a summary report. I have two tables, with products and orders.
I want create this:

[image: Results]

From two tables:

Products

[image: Products]

Orders

[image: Orders]

I try that's query:

```
 SELECT round(SUM(price),2),0)
FROM products, orders
WHERE products.id_products = orders.id_products AND MONTH(orders.date) = 1 AND YEAR(orders.date) = '2019'
GROUP BY products.type
```

for every month, but I have a problem when the product type does not exist in a given month.

Anyone have any solution to generate such a report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT
    p.type_product,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.date) = 2019 AND MONTH(o.date) = 1 THEN o.price ELSE 0 END) January,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.date) = 2019 AND MONTH(o.date) = 2 THEN o.price ELSE 0 END) February
FROM 
    products p
    INNER JOIN orders o ON oid_product. = p.id_product
GROUP BY p.type_product
```

Comment: thanks, +1. Great solution, it works exactly as I wanted